# Dynamic @RequestParam in @RestController

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-restcontroller, http-request-parameters

I have a controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = UserRestController.REST_URL, produces = 
MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class UserRestController {

static final String REST_URL = "/customers";

@GetMapping
public List<User> getAll() {
    return service.getAll();
  }
}
```

It succesfully handle such requests,as:

```
GET:    /customers/
```

And I want to get users by some parameters.For example, email:

```
GET:   /customers?email=someemail@gmail.
```

I tried:

```
@GetMapping("/")
public User getByEmail(@RequestParam(value = "email") String email) {
    return super.getByEmail(email);
}
```

and expectedly I receive an exception, as "/" is already mapped on getAll-class.
Is there any ways to solve this problem?

Comment: try this `@GetMapping("/email")
public User getByEmail(@RequestParam(value = "email") String email) {
    return super.getByEmail(email);
}`

Comment: This way is working, but it mapped on  /customers/email?email=someemail@gmail.  And I need exactly /customers?email=someemail@gmail.

Answer (score 2):

```
@GetMapping
public Object get((@RequestParam(value = "email", required = false) String email) {
    if (email != null && !email.isEmpty()) { 
     return super.getByEmail(email);
    } else {
      return service.getAll();
    }  
}
```

Comment: I tried this.  it returns 404-Error for   /customers&email=someemail@gmail.com   And  404 - for  /customers/

Comment: Do you mean /customers?email=someemail@gmail.com

Comment: Yes. Sorry! I made a mistake.   Responce with 405 when I try /customers&email=someemail@gmail.com

Comment: Is it working now? I have added required false in @RequestParam Annotation

Comment: You added the required = false in @RequestParam?

Comment: I added required = false   and   GET: /customers/   now is workig well.   But  /customers?email=someemail@gmail.com    returns  405

Comment: And one more question, please. If need to use other parameters (besides), could I use something like  public List<User> getByEmailOrAll(@RequestParam(value = "email", required = false) String email, 
                                      @RequestParam(value = "phone" , required = false) String phone)

Comment: Absolutely, give it a shot.

Answer (score 2):

You have to modify your current

```
@GetMapping
public List<User> getAll() {
    return service.getAll();
  }
}
```

method and add the **email** as a request parameter if you want to keep the URL mapping the same.
So it will look like:

```
@GetMapping
public List<User> getAll(@RequestParam(value = "email", required = false) String email) {
    if (!StringUtils.isempty(email)) {
        return super.getByEmail(email);
    } else {
        return service.getAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried.    GET: /customers/ now is workig well. But  GE:      /customers?email=someemail@gmail.com returns 405